# SVN - Commit failed: Can't open file '/svn/repos/myrepository/trunk/format'

Tags: svn, permissions, repository

I recently created a new repository on an SVN installation. When attempting to commit the code base for the first time, I am getting the error `Commit failed: Can't open file '/svn/repos/myrepository/trunk/format'` (Using SmartSVN). Here are some details about the installation:

Repo Config Dir:

```
/svn/repos/myrepository/
```

Repo Files Dirs:

```
/myrepository/trunk, /myrepository/branch, /myrepository/tags
```

I have ensure that both `/svn` and `/myrepository` have `drwxrwx` permissions and `root:root` ownership. Also I ensured the user = root in `/etc/xinetd.d/svn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try having `drwxrwxrwx` and then if it is working then it's a user permissions problem...

just do it using command

```
chmod -R 777 svn_path_here
```

For example I have `drwxrwx` but my owner of svn folder is my username.. that is not the root one...

If you want to change your `svn` owner.. you can do it like this:

```
chown -R myUsernameHere folderPathHere
```

Comment: Great catch. I migrated an svn repository across servers and the permissions got lost. Fixing them resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I change the owner for www-data

chown repositoryPath www-data www-data